# Convert String to Date Time Filed in Azure Data Bricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have the following text string that represents a date time from an application .

2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM

I need to convert this to a date time to do a DATE ADD operation .

I have tried this many ways with no success and it gives me null in Azure Data Bricks .

```
select '2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM' as DateTime_String, 
    to_date('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM', 'yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss:SS a') as Attempt_1  , 
    date_format(date ('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS a") as Attempt_2,
    to_timestamp('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS a') as Attempt_3,
     to_timestamp('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ') as Attempt_4
```

[image: Screenshot of Closest Attempt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following approach to meet your requirement.

1. Convert your *string* to a *unix timestamp* (in seconds)
2. create datetime column in your desired format from the unix timestamp.

the code & output would be as follows:

```
select '2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM' as DateTime_String,unix_timestamp('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa') as unixtimestamp_value, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2021-11-22 07:28:47 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  as desired_format
```

[image]

Comment: Genius. Spark sql - we got to love it